# On the measure of noncompactness

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

I am working on an article based with the notion of [Measure of noncompactness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_of_non-compactness).

Let $ \mathcal {M}_E $ be the family of all nonempty bounded subsets of $ E $ (a Banach space)

> **Definition:**
>
> The function $ \nu: \mathcal{M}_E \rightarrow \mathbb R^ + $ is a measure of noncompactness if, for all $ X, Y \in \mathcal {M}_E $:
>
> 1) $ \nu (X) = \nu (\bar {X}) $.
>
> 2) $ \nu (X) = \nu (Conv (X)) $.
>
> 3) $  X \subset Y \Rightarrow  \nu (X) \leq \nu (Y)$.
>
> 4) $ \nu \big(\lambda X + (1- \lambda) Y \big) \leq \lambda \nu (X) + (1- \lambda) \nu (Y) $, for all $ \lambda \in [0,1] $.
>
> 5) If $ A \in \mathcal {M}_E, $ closed and $ \nu (A) = 0 $ Then, $ A $ is compact.
>
> **6)** If $ A_n \in \mathcal {M}_E $, and $ A_{n+1} \subset A_{n} $ and if $ \lim_{n \to + \infty} \nu (A_n) = 0 $, then: $ A_{\infty} = \bigcap_{n =}^ {+\infty} A_n \neq \emptyset $.

Now, let  $x\in BC(\mathbb R^+)$ ( furnished with the standard supremum norm), i.e $x:\mathbb R ^+\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ bounded, continuous.

Let $$\omega(x,r)=\sup\{|x(t)-x(s)| \colon t,s \in \mathbb R ^+ , \ |t-s|<r\}$$

(called modulus of continuity of $x$ ).

Let us fix $X$ a nonempty bounded subset of $BC(\mathbb R^+)$, and $$\begin{align*}
 \omega(X,r)&= \sup\{\omega(x,r), x\in X\}\\ 
 \omega_0(X)&= \lim_{r\to 0} \omega(X,r)\}
\end{align*}
$$

I need to prove that $\mu$ is a  measure of noncompactness, such that:

$$\mu(X)=\omega_0(X)+\lim_{t\to +\infty } sup\;diamX(t)$$

where $$diamX(t)=sup\{|x(t)-y(t)|:\: x,y \in X\}$$

---

**I showed 1) ... 5) of the definition; How can I get 6) please?**

Comment: I have a question: What is a 'born' subset of a Banach space? It should probably rule out the empty set $\emptyset$, since by 3) and since $\emptyset\subset K$, $K$ compact it would result in $\nu(\emptyset)=0$. Hence choosing $A_n=\emptyset$ in 6) would result in a contradiction.

Comment: Choose $f_n \in A_n$ and try to show that this is a Cauchy-sequence in $BC(\mathbb R^+)$. Then you get a limit which is a candidate for an element of the intersection.

Comment: @humanStampedist : I mean bounded, I forgot to say that $\mathcal M_E$ be the family of all nonempty bounded subsets of  $E$.